# Use of unassigned local variable groupNode

Tags: c#, .net, treeview, web-parts, nodes

Got no clue why I am getting this error for treeView in a Webpart, could be a logical error to be honest,

```
tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);
```

why would it say that :S

```
        protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        try
        {
            int Index = 0;
            TreeView tree = new TreeView();
            TreeNode groupNode; 
            Dictionary<int, string> GroupList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            Dictionary<int, string> UserList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            List<string> IndividualUserList = new List<string>();

            foreach (SPUser user in SPContext.Current.Web.Users)
            {
                string groupName = FormatUserLogin(user.Name);

                if (groupName != "" && groupName != "System Account")
                    IndividualUserList.Add(groupName);
                else if (user.IsDomainGroup && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(groupName) && 
                    Directory.DoesGroupExist(groupName))
                {
                    Index++;
                    GroupList.Add(Index, groupName);
                    List<ADUser> adUsers = Directory.GetUsersFromGroup(groupName);

                    foreach (ADUser member in adUsers)
                    {
                        if (member != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(member.DisplayName))
                            UserList.Add(Index, member.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }

            IndividualUserList.Sort();

            foreach (string Item in IndividualUserList)
            {
                groupNode = new TreeNode(Item);
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> GroupPair in GroupList)
            {
                groupNode = new TreeNode(GroupPair.Value);
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> UserPair in UserList)
                {
                    if (UserPair.Key == GroupPair.Key)
                    {
                        groupNode.ChildNodes.Add(new TreeNode(UserPair.Value));
                    }
                }
            }

            tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);

            this.Controls.Add(tree);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //loggingit
        }
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: This is not related to your question, but you are currently reassigning a new `TreeNode` to your `groupNode` within your `foreach` loops.  I can't imagine this yielding what you want it to yield.

Comment: I am not really sure what am doing with this treeNode tbh, you can call me a noob

Comment: No worries. We have all been there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't explicitly initilize that variable before use of it:

considering this suspicios code:

```
foreach (string Item in IndividualUserList)
{
    groupNode = new TreeNode(Item);
}
```

It's not clear why you need to initialize the *same* instance all over the iteration, but, by the way, none gurantees that `IndividualUserList` is *not* empty, so the variable can remain **not initialized**.

To resolve this problem, at the begining of the function, write

```
TreeNode groupNode = null;
```

or

```
TreeNode groupNode = new TreeNode();
```

**EDIT**

or, as Vlad suggested, coud choose:

```
TreeNode groupNode = default(TreeNode);
```

The choice is based on your code-flow logic.

Comment: I would suggest TreeNode groupNode = default(TreeNode); (in case it's a struct)

Answer (score 0):

Initializing `groupNode` to `null` should help.

```
TreeNode groupNode = null;
```

Comment: it builds up but giving this error, "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index " which could be Logical error I am making :/

Answer (score 0):

If your loops do not execute, the value for `groupNode` will never be assigned. What you could do is do something like so: `TreeNode? groupNode = null;`. This will provide an initial value to the variable and will remove the error/warning. However, I would then recommend the following change:

```
if (groupNode != null)
{
     tree.Nodes.Add(groupNode);
     this.Controls.Add(tree);
} 
else
{
     //Do some logic because the variable is still null.
}
```

Comment: thanks Npinti it solved the Index coming Null problem, but now nothing is coming up, which makes me feel like, I am not developing the treeview properly.

Comment: @TimeToThine: I would recommend you introduce breakpoints to see which segments of your code are running and what are not. I would recommend that you ask another question as to why you are not getting anything on the screen :)

Comment: I would love to ask another question if i had reputation above 125, and i gonna debug it now

Answer (score 0):

While you instantiate the *groupNode* in *if* or *for* blocks only, you should write:

```
TreeNode groupNode = null;
```

Because C# says that it may not reach that lines at *if* or *for* blocks at all!

Answer (score 0):

It only has a value if the second or third for loop has something to iterate over. If there is nothing to iterate over, what should be added to the `Nodes`collection? The compiler wants to make sure you mean `null`<sup>(?)</sup> in this case.